# How to add Confirmation dialog? If press yes, the button will download, if no, the button will cancel

Tags: javascript, php

I have this web page that allows to export the file into excel file. It has a button that when click, it will automatically download the file. Now, I want a confirmation or notification button that prompts the user before downloading. When the "export" button is click, a prompt notification asking to export or not. If the "yes" button is click, then it will export the file, if not, then it cancels.

market.php

```
<button onclick="exportToExcelRequest('tableExport')" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data To Excel File</button>
```

exportToExcelRequest.js

```
function exportToExcelRequest(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadurl;
    var dataFileType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTMLData = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'MarketOrderRequestReport.xls';
    downloadurl = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(downloadurl);
     if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
      var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTMLData], {
      type: dataFileType
     });
       navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
     }else{
      downloadurl.href = 'data:' + dataFileType + ', '+ tableHTMLData;
       downloadurl.download = filename;
       downloadurl.click();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It can be done in different ways, here is the simplest one**

```
<button onclick="if(confirm('agree ?')){exportToExcelRequest('tableExport')}" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data To Excel File</button>
```

*if you have any question, please let me know*

**Another way**

```js
function check(data){
  
  if(confirm("Are you sure ?")){
    
    exportToExcelRequest(data);
    
  }
}


function exportToExcelRequest(data){
      alert(data);
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="check('tableExport')" class="btn btn-primary">Export Data To Excel File</button>
```